# Transferring custom token to a phantom wallet

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, metaplex, token, transfer

I'm just beginning as a solana blockchain developer and I was just wondering, how can I transfer custom tokens on solana devnet to another wallet. It's been confusing me for a bit now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I transfer an SPL token using web3.js?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/how-do-i-transfer-an-spl-token-using-web3-js)

Comment: You should give more context on where and how you created the spl-tokens. I would suggest looking at the solana command line tools. You can create a token and transfer them using the `spl-token` cli tool.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of process have you been through?

Is there any code that you can share?
Or error message you can’t understand